# Shell Wrapper Handle / Execute Interactive Commands Pipes C++ UNIX

Tags: c++, c, unix, pipe, nonblocking

My Project is to Create a little Remote Shell for my Home Unix PC in C / C++. Its components are a server which sends commands to the client via socket connection, which executes the command and sends the output.

Now I would like to execute commands like "login" to authenticate myself on the client.
Is there any way how to handle interactive commands like "login", "python3" - Python3 Shell ???

I've tried to handle this issue with PIPES, so to pipe(), fork() the Process and catch {STDIN; STDOUT; STDERR}, but I couldn't interact with interactive commands, since they block until they are finished.
I just managed to execute "normal" commands like "ls", "arp -a", "ifconfig"... .

Any Ideas, Websites, Code Snippets, Suggestions ???

I appreciate your support,
Regards, from David

Comment: If you have a specific question about programming, please ask it.

Comment: You have a reversed understanding of the common terms `server` and `client` it seems. ;-) On the "client" which executes the command you can use something like e.g. `popen()`. Many tools will work with that. But it would be a bigger effort if you require terminal emulation.

Comment: @reichhart Thanks for your Response !!! I would really love to achieve this using terminal emulation. Do you know any good websites for terminal emulation ??? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this using so called pseudo terminals. The portable function for that is [posix_openpt](https://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_openpt)

Comment: Thanks for your Reponse — This sounds awesome. Do you have any example for that, I‘m just not 100% sure about it

Comment: If you don't need terminal emulation then you most probably don't need this. Something like e.g. `popen()` or your own implementation of that (e.g. without using a shell) would be in most cases sufficient.

Comment: @reichhart Thanks for your response. Your right, in most cases I won't this terminal emulation, but I just want to do it for practice. For example if you`re accidentally typing an interactive command, then the normal procedure won't do it. Thank you buddy

Comment: @datenwolf You were Right, this is what I've been searching for for several months !!!

Answer (score 0):

First, for a shell you don't need a server to handle commands and send response.

to execute commands:
first, you have to check if the command is a builtin command or an UNIX command.
If it's an Unix command you have to create a path to the dir root binary commande (for exemple: the path of python3 is /usr/bin/python3), after that you do a fork, in the child process you can use execve to exec the command and in the parent process you do a wait to catch the signal code.
Else if the command it's a builtin command, you juste have to call the function that you created.
you can go check my github account, there 2 shells that i coded in C,, minishell1 : https://github.com/la-montagne-epitech/Minishell1 and 42Sh (more complete)

Comment: @branimi haroun Thanks for your kind Response !!! I know that you don‘t need a server to implement a shell, I just did it as extra practise. Furthermore your info is helpful and I like your shell!!! Thanks

Comment: 10 seconds required to see the first flaw on `get_char()`. How to distinguish between char 0 and no char? This is faulty code.

Comment: it is not a faulty code, the read function return the size of the n characters that it reads, so if it read the character 0 the retsize will be equal to one and it will return a char and if retsize equal to 0 than we return an integer 0 that correspend to the '\0' char, take a look at the ascii code, may be you'll understand.